# lubridate and ifelse

Tags: r, lubridate

UPDATE: Clarified the question and code in response to a commenter.

I am not seeing why `date.ie` creates a POSIXct object but `date.ipt` creates a numeric object. In both cases I am using lubridate to add days to a date.

```
set.seed(34859)
date.ie = (ymd("2013/07/01", tz="Africa/Nairobi")) + days(round(runif(10)*(150), 
                                         digits=0))

# creates this POSIXct object
# structure(c(1382821200, 1373922000, 1385326800, 1385154000, 1381093200, 
#             1381870800, 1372971600, 1377982800, 1382216400, 1383512400), class = c("POSIXct", 
#                                                                                    "POSIXt"), tzone = "Africa/Nairobi")

date.ie <- format(date.ie, format="%Y-%m-%d")

# creates this character object
# c("2013-10-27", "2013-07-16", "2013-11-25", "2013-11-23", "2013-10-07", 
#   "2013-10-16", "2013-07-05", "2013-09-01", "2013-10-20", "2013-11-04"
# )

date.ie2 <- ymd(date.ie)
treat <- rep(0:1, 5)
start.ipt <- (sample(x=c(0,1), size=10, replace=TRUE,                
                     prob=c(.5, .5))) # changed to even prob for small dataset
```

---

Update 2:

This next chunk was my old approach, and it did not work because of how `ifelse` behaves. Thanks, @hadley, for pointing this out.

```
date.ipt <- ifelse(treat==0 & start.ipt==1,
                   date.ie2 + days(round(runif(10)*(90), digits=0)),
                   ifelse(treat==1 & start.ipt==1,
                          date.ie2 + days(round(runif(100)*(60), digits=0)),NA))

# creates this numeric object
# c(1384992000, 1375488000, NA, NA, NA, 1385337600, 1375142400, 
# 1381449600, 1383782400, 1384560000)

date.ipt = format(data$date.ipt, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Here is my fix. Rather than using ifelse to create date.ipt in one step, I do it in several. I get to where I want to be, but it takes a while. Hopefully commenters will have suggestions about how to do this more efficiently.

```
date.ipt.c <- date.ie2 + days(round(runif(10)*(90), digits=0))
date.ipt.c = format(date.ipt.c, format="%Y-%m-%d")

date.ipt.t <- date.ie2 + days(round(runif(10)*(60), digits=0))
date.ipt.t = format(date.ipt.t, format="%Y-%m-%d")

date.ipt <- ifelse(treat==1 & start.ipt==1, date.ipt.t, ifelse(treat==0 & start.ipt==1, date.ipt.c, NA))
date.ipt <- format(date.ipt, format="%Y-%m-%d")
date.ipt2 <- ymd(date.ipt)

days.to.ipt <- difftime(date.ipt2, date.ie2, tz="Africa/Nairobi", units="days")

data <- data.frame(date.ie, treat, start.ipt, date.ipt, days.to.ipt)
```

Comment: `format` is not a lubridate function, and does not convert Date objects. It's a base function for pretty-printing strings. Ican't decide, by reading your code, in what format is your `date.ipt` variable.

Comment: Also, when asking a question, please provide the minimum amount of code and data to make your example reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, juba. If you run what I posted, you will be able to reproduce, no? `> class(data$date.ipt)
[1] "character"`

Comment: Yes, but it's a pain. It would be better just to provide your resulting date.ipt vector and the code doesn't work. And this doesn't tell us what the format of your date.ipt is : is it a timestamp, something else ? How could we convert it to date/time ?

Comment: @juba, I updated my post with a more minimal reproducible example. I wanted to keep a few inputs to the ifelse statement on `date.ipt` in the hopes that it will clarify my problem.

Comment: Don't use `ifelse`, or if you do, read the documentation to see what it returns: "A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and class) as test and ..."

Comment: Thanks, @hadley. I had not noticed this behavior of ifelse. I changed the title to reflect that this issue relates to ifelse. I also edited the post to show a potential solution. It is not a great approach, but it works. I'd appreciate any thoughts about how to approach this differently.